# How should I unwrap a member variable that's optional but most likely set?

Tags: swift

I have a class that runs a function inside the init/constructor that loops over an array of...

```
struct Answer {
   let correct: Bool
   let text: String
}
```

...and searches for an object that has the **correct** boolean variable set to **true**. The loop and search is done via a function named **getCorrectId()** that returns a index to where the **Answer** with the **correct: true** is placed.

The function is implemented like this:

```
private func getCorrectId() -> Int? {
   for i in 0..<self.answers.count {
      if self.answers[i].correct {
         return i
      }
   }

   return nil
}
```

As you can see, the function returns an optional integer. In 99.9% of the cases it should not fail, and if it fails it is because I've made an logical programming error by myself somewhere in the code.

### SolutionHandler class, including init() and getCorrectId() function

```
struct Answer {
   let correct: Bool
   let text: String
}

class SolutionHandler { 

   var correctId: Int?
   var answers = [Answer]()

   init(correctSolution: String, incorrectSolutions: [String]) {

      // Add the correct solution to the answers array
      self.answers.append(Answer(correct: true, text: correctSolution))

      // Add the incorrect solutions to the answers array
      for incorrectSolution in incorrectSolutions {
         self.answers.append(Answer(correct: false, text: incorrectSolution))
      }

      // Shuffle the answers to make them random in array
      self.answers.shuffle()

      <-- IMPORTANT PART

      // Find the correct id (with forced unwrap)
      self.correctId = getCorrectId()!

      -->
   }

   private func getCorrectId() -> Int? {
      for i in 0..<self.answers.count {
         if self.answers[i].correct {
            return i
         }
      }

      return nil
   }
}
```

So, to my main question... how should I unwrap this optional? Is it okay to force unwrap it or should I make the class **SolutionHandler** be set to **nil** if **getCorrectId()** function fails and handle it whenever I create the class? Or should I maybe throw an custom error and catch it whenever I create this class?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: throwing error option is completely unsuitable here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know which one is correct; it's always the first one, as guaranteed by the way you constructed the `answers` array.

I think a better solution to the problem would be to not mix together all answers into a single array. Something like this:

```
class SolutionHandler { // FIXME: this is probably a bad name for this, and it should probably be a struct.
    let correctAnswer: Answer
    let incorrectAnswers: [Answer]
    var answers: [Answer] { incorrectAnswers + [correctAnswer] }

    init(correctSolution: String, incorrectSolutions: [String]) {
       self.correctAnswer = Answer(correct: true, text: correctSolution)
       self.incorrectAnswers = incorrectSolutions.map { Answer(correct: false, text: $0) }
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, the class is not named **SolutionHandler** in my real project, it was only to make the example code a bit more understandable! :)

Comment: And thanks for the input, I think you're right in that I should split the **correctAnswer** and **incorrectAnswers** into two different variables. But why do you suggest a struct instead of a class?

Comment: @Warcaith I think a better name would be `SolutionSet` (because there's no "handling" here of any kind, and there shouldn't be). `SolutionSet` should be a struct because solution sets don't have defined concept of identity. If two solution sets contain the same answers, with the same texts, then they're indistinguishable. This is unlike other things, like people, where two people might have the same properties (first name, last name, height, etc.) and be distinguishable.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the thing is that I need in a way to shuffle the answers, both the correct and incorrect, and then get the ID of the correct one. Do you suggest that another class should handle that and use this struct only as a container?

Comment: @Warcaith Point of clarity: there are no IDs here, only indices. Indices are a weak form of ID, because they only apply to a `(item, location in array, point in time)`, whereas the whole point of real IDs it to apply to an item, irrespective of where it is, and when it's checked. E.g. the moment you shuffle, all your IDs are invalidated.

Comment: @Warcaith I don't see why shuffling requires this be a class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202169/discussion-between-alexander-and-warcaith).

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
if result = getCorrectId() {
  self.correctId = result
}
```

Only assign the result of `getCorrectID()` if it is not `nil`.

Comment: `self.correctId = getCorrectId()` is ok as `correctId ` is optional

Comment: But the "self.correctId" needs to be set, or else the class will not work as intended.

Comment: Well if you are 200% sure there is always a correct answer, then yes, you can probably force unwrap it. But I would also rethink the design of `SolutionHandler` to prevent this situation.